# I'm trying to make a unit test for a Spring Controller but i'm getting 404 instead of 200

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

I'm trying to make a unit test for a Spring Controller but i'm getting 404 instead of 200


Here is my controller method :

```
    @Timed
    @PostMapping(value = "/aaa/bbb", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    @ApiOperation(value = "")
    public ModelAndView redirectPsnResponseForCgu(@RequestParam final MultiValueMap<String, String> formData,
                                                  final ModelMap model) {
        ....
    }
```

Here is my test method

```
@Test
    public void should_intercept_and_redirect() throws Exception {
        final MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        formData.add("pa", "test");
        formData.add("par", "test");
        formData.add("param", "test");

        final String content = AppUtils.printJson(formData.toSingleValueMap(), true);

        this.mvc.perform(
                post("/base-url/aaa/bbb")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
                        .params(formData)
                        .header("origin", "*"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

This is the test results. I don't understand why the 404 status ! Could you see if i'm missing something in my code ?

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /base-url/aaa/bbb
       Parameters = {pa=[test], par=[test], param=[test]}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", origin:"*"]
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Access-Control-Allow-Origin:"*", Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:"false", Access-Control-Allow-Methods:"GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS", Access-Control-Max-Age:"3600", Access-Control-Allow-Headers:"Origin, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, username", Access-Control-Expose-Headers:"Content-Length, Content-Disposition, Authorization"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :404
```

Comment: above code works perfectly fine for me. check if the url is right?

Comment: @pvpkiran The url is fine, that is why i'm confused !

Comment: how r u initializing your `mvc` and also is it only this method or all the methods in this controller are failing?

Comment: @pvpkiran : For my `mvc`, i'm injecting it with `@Autowired`. And all the methods in this controller are failing !

Comment: You shud  edit the question and put the relevant code, like what are the annotations u have on the class and how u r initializing etc

Comment: @pvpkiran : my bad, it was a mistake in the `@WebMvcTest()` I was using `MyControllerTest.class` instead `MyController.class`. Problem solved